# Ubuntu 12.04 iso image file too large to burn to DVD?

Tags: 12.04

I just downloaded the Ubuntu 12.04 iso file in order to do a fresh install. However, I am not able to burn it to my DVD which only holds 4.7GB because it is too big (>6GB).

Comment: Hi I am not sure what you are asking? Would you like to find a smaller download, or an alternative way to install? Or are you just interested in finding out why the download was so big?

Answer (score 2):

You must have been downloading from a different source, or something went terrible wrong during the download. Ubuntu 12.04 has a size of 695 MB. Small enough to fit on a CD. Ubuntu 12.10 however do require a DVD (~800 MB).

Please get the iso file from Ubuntu.com

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop